# asp.net mvc html layout templates

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-4, formatting, datatables

I am looking for a theme / template that I can use with asp.net mvc.

I am building a web application and I do not want to have to make every detail my self. Where can I find templates such as ones on Themeforest.com but for asp.net which can aid me in developing a better looking and better functioning site.

And if not what I have mentioned above, then is there not maybe a library some where of code snippets of code for example a table template that has the table structure, the ability to sort it's data, resize the columns etc.

Thanks